# How to check to see if there is a decimal in textbox

Tags: c#

I am new to c#. I am making a universal app and trying to have a user only be able to input one decimal into a textbox. I have seen that a lot of people suggesting to use KeyPressed event but that does not work for me. So far I have the following working code:

```
private void tbTotal_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key < Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number0 || e.Key >= Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number9)
        {
            if (e.Key < Windows.System.VirtualKey.NumberPad0 || e.Key >= Windows.System.VirtualKey.NumberPad9)
            {
                if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Decimal)
                {
                        e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How am I able to get it to allow only one decimal? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Trying to validate a decimal field while the user types is not a good strategy.  It is better to validate after the user finishes typing.  See [Textbox check with Regex expression not allowing decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17797870/10263) to see why.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

```
private void tbTotal_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    byte a = (byte)e.KeyCode;
    if(e.KeyCode!=Keys.Delete)
    if(a!=8&&a!=13)
    if(a<48||a>57) e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: KeyPress does not work for me. I get the error "The type or namespace name 'KeyPressEventArgs' could not be found.

Comment: well just add  `using System.Windows.Forms;` to the top of page

Comment: ya adding using System.Windows.Forms; does not make it work either. I am not able to use KeyPress at all

Comment: so i edited because Keys.Delete and e.KeyCode were giving errors to the following: `Windows.System.VirtualKey.Delete` and `e.Key`. I am able to enter numbers but not from the numpad nor am I able to enter any decimals.